# Error : Failed to load bundle localhost:8081

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just have an issue when i run react-native run-ios, following message is showing and i think it's related to babel :

[image: React native bundle error]

Someone has already this issue please ?

```
"GET /index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `/Volumes/SD/react/PropertyFinder/index.js`: Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

thank you

Comment: Have you tried deleting you're node modules and then try npm install?

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, yes i have, but issue persist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have same issue.
I tried to install

> npm add @babel/runtime

then

> npm install

It works for me, i hope it helps you.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes different programs use same ports like 80,8080 or 8081, when I face this problem I set the default port to 8088. And It works perfect.

Try

`react-native run-ios --port=8088`

If changing port isn't work, try this. This will install the @babel/runtime package to your project.

`npm add @babel/runtime`

`npm install`

After this re-compile your project.

I hope it works.

Answer (score 5):

Soluton that works:

```
rm -rf ios/build/; kill $(lsof -t -i:8081)
```

Comment: Please explain your solution and why it works so that others can understand.

Comment: ok, this works for me, but kill command was useless. I don't completely understand why works removing the build directory, and it didn't after clean the project on xcode.

Answer (score 0):

open file 'package.json' => add "build:ios" in "scripts"

```
"scripts": {
   "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle- 
                 output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'",
}
```

npm run build:ios