# Fail to load funding localhost:8081/index.bundle

Tags: react-native

I am new to REACT-NATIVE, since yesterday, the react-native cli is not working fine. First, it is not able to execute "react-native run-is" because some path issue. Then it fixed this morning. After people fixed it, it got problem run the app in simulator. It has error that failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?...) I tried the following suggestion from other post.

1. run npm install
2. delete the node_module and run npm install
3. change the port number to something else.

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.1"   },   
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
    "eslint": "^5.15.3",
    "jest": "^24.5.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"   },   
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"   }
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure you can connect to internet or host computer from simulator. If not check Wi-Fi connection in simulator.

Comment: The computer/simulator has the internet connection. Even though the app that work before it is not working too

Comment: Are you using genymotion ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error : Failed to load bundle localhost:8081](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637341/error-failed-to-load-bundle-localhost8081)